# Spring Hibernate не создает таблиц

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, entity

В классе сущности `@Entity` не создаются таблицы в аннотациях `@Table` и `@CollectionTable`. Ошибка:

> cannot resolve table.

В `application.properties` прописал строку `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` и настроил подключение к базе `postgres`, сами сущности создаются нормально.

Работаю в `IDEA` соединение с базой данных настроил в разделе `View->Tool Windows->Database`.

Если я все правильно понял, то я сказал `Spring` самому создавать нужные таблицы и колонки, почему тогда возникает данная ошибка?

Ниже приведен фрагмент кода, жирным показаны места где возникают ошибки `cannot resolve table`:

```
@Entity    
@Table(name = "**usr**")    
public class User {       
  @Id
  
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  
  @CollectionTable(name = "**user_role**", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "**user_id**"))
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что звездочки `**` могут использоваться в именах таблиц?

Comment: Звездочек в коде нет, я пометил так чтобы лучше видино было